# Given that $(1-\frac{t}{n})^{n} \leq e^{-t}$ is $(1-\frac{t}{n})^{n-1}\leq e^{-t}$ also true?

Tags: limits, inequality

I have the given proposition in a book that i want to use:

$\forall r,n \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $n \geq 1$ and $|t| \leq n$
$$(1-\frac{t}{n})^{n} \leq e^{-t}$$

So since $|t| \leq n$, in my particular case $t = 1$ in fact, this product keeps getting smaller and smaller when $n$ increases.
What I am wondering is if I want to use the bound like this:
$$(1-\frac{t}{n})^{n-1} \leq e^{-t}$$ Would I have to specify any more details to make it nicer on the reader? The only thing I have done is to check on wolfram alpha if they both converge to $e^{-t}$ and this is the case.

Comment: False for $n=2$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I just checked, actually what I am saying does not come true before $n=94917165$.

Comment: @DenLilleMand It is easy to prove that $(1 - t/n)^{n-1} > e^{-t}$ for all $n\ge 1$ and $t\in (0, 1)$.

Comment: @DenLilleMand Also, $(1-t/n)^{n-1} < e^{-t}$ for all $n\ge 2$ and $t \ge 2$.